# Why Design layout does not work in laravel in auth:make command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm using laravel 5.6 but the problem is when I run auth:make command it execute and display some login field and register field. My question is why front end desing is not working after running auth:make command in laravel. I have uploaded image it shows only html content but front-end desing is not showing.

[image: Image link]

Comment: what do you mean by design layout, can you share all these ?

Comment: actually it was not installation problem. it was the problem of htaccess file. when i remove htaccess file form public to root directory then this problem was arise

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

```
app/resources/views/auth/layouts/app.blade.php.
```

find this (line 20 probably):

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and replace it with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it works for me laravel 8.x.

Answer (score -1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend

While Laravel does not dictate which JavaScript or CSS pre-processors you use, it does provide a basic starting point using Bootstrap and Vue that will be helpful for many applications. By default, Laravel uses NPM to install both of these frontend packages.

So if you want to use default "front end design" (bootstrap) that comes default by Laravel, and want to use method that Laravel recommends(npm) than you must follow the documentation above.

Did you install node and npm then run the following commands in your laravel root directory ?

```
npm install


npm run dev
```

These commands compile related javascript and scss/css files and build your front end.

Also following are some other documents about this subject :

**Installation of Node & npm :**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://nodejs.org/en/

https://www.npmjs.com

**Laravel Mix And the Front-end :**

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/14?autoplay=true

Comment: Why npm is required ?

Comment: npm is a package manager for node. It installs javascript packages. It makes installing required packages really easy. If you do not want to install npm to you production environment : You can install node and npm to your development environment. After you executed the commands in the answer you can upload your frontend to your production environment.

Comment: All you are saying is good but Its not related to the problem and not required here.

Comment: It is related and must be installed if we want front end advantages of Laravel framework. Looking at picture provided, you can see that CSS is missing. If we run npm install and npm run dev related css and javascript files will be generated. So the problem will be solved. It is related.

Comment: its optional to use node.js not necessary. laravel can handle front-end and back-end both.

Comment: If you want to write all css by hand then you are right. For compiling sass files, npm is needed. If npm can be installed without node than your are right.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm   npm is distributed with Node.js . If there is an alternate method without installing node your are right. If not then I am right.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend . While Laravel does not dictate which JavaScript or CSS pre-processors you use, it does provide a basic starting point using Bootstrap and Vue that will be helpful for many applications. By default, Laravel uses NPM to install both of these frontend packages.  So if the user wants to code css without bootstrap then its OK, no need for npm. But if user wants to use bootstrap then npm is needed, then node is needed.